# Can I have a conditional MySQLi insert based on PHP if statement

Tags: php, mysql, session, if-statement, mysqli

I am trying to use a single .php page to have a conditional MySQLi INSERT based on user role.  Basically, the INSERT is very similar with the exception of a couple of fields.  Here is my code:

```
require 'scripts/config.php'; 

            if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin')
                 { 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO aircraft_dataV2 (status, ac_cat, ac_type, faa_id, time_in, date_in, time_out, date_out, services, comments, contact_name, contact_phone, contact_ext, contact_email, email, csr_lsr, created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
                {
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssssssssss", $status, $ac_cat, $ac_type, $faa_id, $time_in, $date_in, $time_out, $date_out, $services, $comments, $contact_name, $contact_phone, $contact_ext, $contact_email, $email, $csr_lsr, $created);


  ...CODE TO $_REQUEST FORM DATA ...


            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
                    {
                        //Redirect to 
                    $aircraft_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);         
                    header("Location: service_confirm.php?aircraft_id=$aircraft_id");
                    } else
                    {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                  }

                }



            if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'client')
                 { 
                SAME as above minus the $csr/lsr and $email fields
                 }
```

What happens is that regardless of the user $_SESSION, both INSERT statements execute.  One entry is blank and the other has the correct data based on the form submitted.

My form is the same with the exception of a couple of conditional fields that are different based on admin vs client.

Can I do this or do I need to go back to the original script that has two different .php pages that contains the INSERT statement for admin vs client like this:

```
            if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin')
                 { 
                  header("Location: admin.php")
                 }

            if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'client')
                 { 
                  header("Location: client.php")
                 }
```

Comment: Time to read up on the [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement or use an associative array lookup table (e.g. `array('admin' => 'admin.php', 'client' => 'client.php')` instead of this mess of `if` statements.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, you can do this. However, something is amiss here. Can you show us a bit more code? What does your form look like? Also, a show us a bit more of the file that has the SQL statements.

Comment: And how is your form calling this code? I suspect this code is being called twice (maybe a header/redirect). You are not checking if the form was submitted.

Comment: The form action is to the same page the php code is on.  I have validation and and I am also checking to see there is an active session logged as well as if form has been submitted ... was trying not to publish over 400 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this.

You either have the wrong session role set which you can easily find out by placing traces or you something is wrong with the query you think you are running. Either way, we can't tell with this sample alone.

Try and print out some data in both condition statements to see in which it really goes into.

Comment: session role are working correctly.  I can echo them on the form prior to submit and on the confirmation page after the submit.  If logged in as a client, I get a confirmation page that echos all the data inserted but if I log into the database, I see a double entry, one that is blank and one that is correct.  What additional code should I provide to this question to help solve the problem, my form is kind of long (about 15 fields ... or 16 if and admin).

Comment: your database queries

Answer (score -1):

I had to step back for a moment to recollect my thoughts.  There were several errors (too many to describe here).  I have it working now (and I learned a little about switch statement).  If this thread needs to be deleted, please do so or tell me how.  Thanks